# Dependencies issue with automatic modules using gradle with java9+

Tags: java, gradle, java-11

I am trying to migrate old project into java 11.

```
dependencies {
    implementation ('com.google.code.findbugs:jsr305:3.0.2')
    implementation ('javax.xml.ws:jaxws-api:2.3.1')
}
```

These both include annotations and other libraries complains about them like this:

```
error: module jsr305 reads package javax.annotation from both java.annotation and jsr305
error: module vboxjws reads package javax.annotation from both java.annotation and jsr305
error: module io.sentry reads package javax.annotation from both java.annotation and jsr305
error: module com.fasterxml.jackson.databind reads package javax.annotation from both java.annotation and jsr305
error: module com.fasterxml.jackson.dataformat.yaml reads package javax.annotation from both java.annotation and jsr305
error: module com.fasterxml.jackson.annotation reads package javax.annotation from both java.annotation and jsr305
```

The solutions I found are 3:

## 1

```
configurations.all {
    exclude module: 'javax.annotation-api'
}
```

## 2

```
configurations.all {
resolutionStrategy {
        preferProjectModules()
        dependencySubstitution {

            substitute(module("javax.annotation:javax.annotation-api")).with(module("com.google.code.findbugs:jsr305:3.0.2"))

}}}
```

## 3

```
implementation ('javax.xml.ws:jaxws-api:2.3.1') {
        exclude group: 'javax.annotation', module: 'javax.annotation-api'
    }
```

and they all lead into another error:

```
Error occurred during initialization of boot layer
java.lang.module.FindException: Module java.annotation not found, required by java.xml.ws
```

This is an example, I have about 20 libraries in the project and there are multiple collisions, I read another option would be to manually combine all jars into one, but I would really like to avoid that. Is there a way how to solve this issue in gradle?

Comment: I think Gradle specific the answer might just be No. You can pretty much wait for the libraries to solve for such conflicting package resolution if internal to them. Or else other hacks are available as you know of them. IMHO, the migration to modules was reliant on a bottom-up migration approach.

Comment: If I take in account for how long java9 is out then it might take .. forever ?

Comment: I guess that's the reason people have readily solved it with using aggregated jars and excluding specific transitive dependency. Just for the case you've shared, there might just be an existing solution though.

Answer (score 0):

```
configurations {
all {
    resolutionStrategy {
        preferProjectModules()
        dependencySubstitution {
            substitute(module("jakarta.annotation:jakarta.annotation-api")).with(module("com.google.code.findbugs:jsr305:3.0.2"))
        }
    }
}}
```